# Inserting document links on form pages on the fly

Tags: html

Opening SP webpage to collect data. Each time the page is opened a unique tracking # is created. I also want to create a word doc in the library named tracking#.doc So far so good my team says.

Lastly I want a link at the bottom of the web form to the newly created .doc they say the link can't be created and the user would have to save the form, exit to the library and open the word doc. It's too cumbersome for the casual user.

Isn't it possible to build the html at opening with the library link /unique tracking.doc appended?

help!

Comment: This sounds simple. Did they explain why they couldn't do it? For example, are you sure the tracking # is created when the page is opened, not when the user saves the page?

Comment: Thanks Christopher. They advised it's upon opening but it seems to create the html link to the doc is not out of the box sharepoint operation and would require custom code which they can't / won't do.

Comment: And the creation of the unique tracking # doesn't require custom code? Anyway, if it's a regular SharePoint form, just add a Content Editor Web Part, a couple lines of JavaScript, done! Or do it via a workflow if this is allowed in your environment.